# How do i add text on an image, but at the top of the screen?

Tags: python, tkinter

I know about compound = 'center' but that only puts it in the middle of the screen. is there a way for me to place it at the top of the screen and then other labels below it, so that the background is acting like a background and not a label so i can place text ontop?

the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()

image = Image.open('heartBg.png')
tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

label = tk.Label(root, text='Some Plain Text', image=tk_image, compound = "center")
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can't do it using label. However you can put images and texts in a `Canvas`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to 'center' the compound argument can be 'bottom', 'top', 'right', 'left', or 'none'.  BTW: compound relates to the image, not the text.  So if you want text at the top set compound=bottom

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()

image = Image.open('heartBg.png')
tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

label = tk.Label(root, text='Some Plain Text', image=tk_image, compound = 'top')
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: OP wants the text ontop (i.e. overlay inside) the image.